# Use function template instances as property accessors

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, properties

I'm using Microsoft's `__declspec(property())` language extension to provide a variety of accessors to one single bunch of data. I'm trying to cut the number of accessor functions I actually have to write by using function templates, but I'm having trouble making it work. There is not a whole lot of information on the MSDN website on what you can and can't do either, so it's kind of tricky.

Ideally I would want something like this :

```cpp
struct vec2
{
    float x, y;
    vec2(float x, float y) : x(x), y(y) {}
};

struct vec4
{
    union 
    {
        struct { float x, y, z, w; };
        float data[4];
    };
    
    template <int a, int b> inline vec2 get()
    {
        return vec2(data[a], data[b]);
    }
    
    template <int a, int b> inline void set(const vec2& v)
    {
        data[a] = v.x;
        data[b] = v.y;
    }
    
    // Specifying explicit template parameters does not work and gives
    // a syntax error on character '<'
    __declspec(property(get = get<0, 0>)) vec2 xx;
    __declspec(property(get = get<0, 1>, put = set<0, 1>)) vec2 xy;
    __declspec(property(get = get<0, 2>, put = set<0, 2>)) vec2 xz;
    __declspec(property(get = get<0, 3>, put = set<0, 3>)) vec2 xw;
    // etc
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vec4 v;
    
    v.xy = vec2(1.f, 2.f);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I also gave some thought to maybe using `std::bind` to pass integral constants as function arguments instead of template parameters, but again, it seems that you're pretty limited in what you're allowed to write in the `get` and `put` fields. If all else fails I'll generate all the code with a script, but I was wondering if there was a way around that.

Comment: Instead of that `union` that I suspect you'll use for type punning, have you considered using a `std::variant`?

Comment: That type punning is UB.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: but OP doesn't want variant but "alias".

Comment: @TedLyngmo I did mean `union` ; as I mentioned I'm trying to read the same data in different ways. @Jarod42 how is it UB ? Not that it's a valid counter-argument, but I've seen this used everywhere, and from my experience it has always worked fine - specifically because I use VC++'s non-standard extension of anonymous structs in unions.

Comment: Since the Windows API code is littered with type punning that is supposed to work in both C and C++,  it's probably defined as an extension as you say. I'd try to find it in print before making use of it in pure C++ code though. "_from my experience it has always worked fine_" - doesn't really say much. UB is UB.

Comment: At the end of the day it is not the end of the world as I can - and will - get rid of that union and do everything through `__declspec(property())`. Good to know though.